# failed to push to heroku (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

```
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:



!     Compiled slug size: 917.2M is too large (max is 500M).
remote:  !     See: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 5788bbafef87b6c05d42cc0d2d3175846ae109bf
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 5788bbafef87b6c05d42cc0d2d3175846ae109bf
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to appname.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/appname.git
```

please help! have already cleared the cache of the buildpacks. that didn't seem to work. tried pushing code to a different branch and that didn't work either. not sure what's going on. I am the only one working on this project and have only been pushing on master. My app has a lot of photo files don't know if thats the issue?

Comment: Did you read http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size?  If so, what of its recommendations did you try, and what was their effect?

Comment: Why is your slug so big? Are you including development dependencies?

Comment: @Chris no I am not. Not sure why the slug is so big? I recently added 80 images of 10MB or less but don't think that is the issue?

Comment: @torek I tried purging the build cache but that didn't seem to change anything. I don't have any huge files, nothing over 10MB.. all files are photos. Don't really have anything to .slugignore either..

Comment: One of the bits of advice on that page is to put large files outside the slug: "Here are some techniques for reducing slug size: ... Move large assets like PDFs or audio files to asset storage." 80 images of "10MB or less" = "800 MB or less", even if it's "less" such as 5 MB each, that's maybe 400 MB of images.